# Problem with Tangent of an Angle

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a setup with two vectors. $\vec x = (10,0,0)$ and $\vec y = (10,3,0)$ By rotating around the xy origin I can create a projected circle of radius 3. I wanted to find the angle between $\vec x$ and $\vec y$.

I did this with the very simple $tan(\theta) = \frac{3}{10}$ which results in $\theta = 0.29146$ radians or $16.7\deg$ This all made sense, but when I choose to launch a projectile  from the origin at $16.7\deg$, it was not hitting the edge of this circle. After a lot of debugging, I ended up halving the angle and suddenly the projectile was hitting the edge of this circle.

Can anyone explain to me what I did wrong, or what is happening here?

Edit: Below is the code for the projectile and angles, this was done in Unity3D

```
public class Crosshair : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject projectile;
List<Vector3> points;
float i = 0;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    points = new List<Vector3>();
    projectile = (GameObject) Instantiate(projectile, transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(16.7f/2, 0, 0));
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (i < 100)
    {
        projectile.transform.Translate(-projectile.transform.forward);
        points.Add(projectile.transform.position);
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        Vector3 prev = transform.position;
        foreach (Vector3 p in points)
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(prev, p, Color.magenta);
            prev = p;
        }
    }
}

void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
    Gizmos.DrawSphere(transform.position + transform.forward * 10 + transform.up * 3, 0.1f);
    Gizmos.DrawSphere(transform.position + transform.forward * 10 + transform.up * -3, 0.1f);
    Gizmos.DrawSphere(transform.position + transform.forward * 10 + transform.right * 3, 0.1f);
    Gizmos.DrawSphere(transform.position + transform.forward * 10 + transform.right * -3, 0.1f);

    Gizmos.color = Color.cyan;
    Gizmos.DrawSphere(transform.position + transform.forward * 10, 0.1f);

    Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position + transform.forward * 10, transform.position + transform.forward * 10 + transform.up * 3);
}
```

}

Comment: The word "debugging" makes me think that you're using some sort of program to simulate the launch. It's possible that there is some error in your code that was somehow doubling the angle after it was input, but that's impossible for anyone here to say as it stands. You should probably post your old code and describe the program you're using. Hopefully someone will be able to help you figure out the issue.

Comment: @CameronBuie I am using software, I will post the code as well, but I don't think that is affecting anything.

Comment: Well, there's nothing wrong with your math, so I'd suspect that it's either the code or one of the programs you're using.